# Elasticseach change sql to Query with ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, ongr

I'm trying to convert an mysql-query to a query for Elasticsearch, but I think I am on the wrong way.

The mysql-query looks like the following:

`WHERE foo = 0 OR (foo = 1 AND bar LIKE "%blub%")`

The Elasticseach-query is created like the following:

```
 $fieldFoo = 'attributes.core.foo.raw';
 $fieldBar = 'attributes.core.bar.raw';

 $firstQuery = new BoolQuery();
 $firstQuery->add(new TermQuery($fieldBar, "0"), BoolQuery::SHOULD);

 $secondQuery = new BoolQuery();
 $secondQuery->add(new WildcardQuery($fieldFoo, "*" . $value . "|*"));
 $secondQuery->add(new TermQuery($fieldBar, "1"));

 $firstQuery->add($secondQuery, BoolQuery::MUST);

 $search->addQuery($query);
```

But this one does not work. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works now:

```
$fieldFoo = 'attributes.core.foo.raw';
$fieldBar = 'attributes.core.bar.raw';
$query = new BoolQuery();

$firstQuery = new BoolQuery();
$firstQuery->add(new TermQuery($fieldBar, "0"), BoolQuery::SHOULD);`enter code here`

$secondQuery = new BoolQuery();
$secondQuery->add(new WildcardQuery($fieldFoo, "*" . $value . "|*"), BoolQuery::SHOULD);
$secondQuery->add(new TermQuery($fieldBar, "1"), BoolQuery::SHOULD);

$firstQuery->add($secondQuery, BoolQuery::SHOULD);

$query->add($firstQuery, BoolQuery::MUST);
```